# Y axis labels are not ordered like the bars in seaborn

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, visualization

I have a data frame called ***general_stats*** that has information about YouTube channels like title, number of subscribers and such.
I want to plot the channels name against the number of subscribers for each in a bar plot using seaborn. but when I try to order the bars by the number of subs they get ordered but the y axis labels stay the same.

This is before ordering :

```
fprop = fm.FontProperties(fname='FontsKR/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.otf')

names = general_stats['Channel_name']
subs = general_stats['Subscribers_Count']

fig = sns.barplot(x=subs, y=names, palette ='Blues_r').set_yticklabels(labels = 
names,fontproperties=fprop, fontsize=12)
fig ;
```

which gives me this result :

[image: before]

and this is after ordering :

```
fprop = fm.FontProperties(fname='FontsKR/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.otf')

names = general_stats['Channel_name']
subs = general_stats['Subscribers_Count']

fig = sns.barplot(x=subs, y=names, palette ='Blues_r', order= 
general_stats.sort_values('Subscribers_Count', 
ascending=False).Channel_name).set_yticklabels(labels = names,fontproperties=fprop, 
fontsize=12)
fig;
```

and it gives me this plot:

[image: after]

as you can see, the bars got ordered but the y axis labels stayed the same. how can i order them with the bars without ordering the data frame itself ?
i have to set the ytick labels myself so i can display the chinese/korean/japanese characters. maybe its because i set the yticklabels **after** the bars were ordered ? how can i bypass this cause i do need the font that i am using !

Comment: I cant add direct images because i am still new to the site..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this happens because you set the y tick labels after the bars were ordered, so you need to use the sorted names there as well. Try this:

```py
fprop = fm.FontProperties(fname='FontsKR/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.otf')

names = general_stats['Channel_name']
subs = general_stats['Subscribers_Count']

names_ordered = general_stats.sort_values('Subscribers_Count', 
                                          ascending=False).Channel_name

ax = sns.barplot(x=subs, y=names, palette='Blues_r', 
                 order=names_ordered)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels=names_ordered, fontproperties=fprop, fontsize=12)
```

Comment: Note that `sns.barplot` doesn't return a `fig`, but an `ax`.  Further, note that `result = sns.barplot(...).set_yticklabels(...)` would put the list of generated text elements into result.  It is very confusing to name that result `fig`.  If you want to change the font properties without changing the labels, it is recommended to call `ax.tick_params(...)` instead.

Comment: @JohanC Agreed. I have slightly edited the code according to your suggestion, although I kept the `set_yticklabels` method, because I do not know how one would use `ax.tick_params` with the `matplotlib.font_manager` object `fprop`.